# What are the default extended file attributes for /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, permissions

I made a mistake when editing `/etc/fstab`. Opened using `vim` instead of `sudoedit` (ie. without permissions) and being lazy to type changes twice, I saved file elsewhere and just `mv` it to correct location. Bad move! I've lost ownership and all extended file permissions(ownership alone is not sufficient), which prohibited the KDE to even boot.

I figured out one from different linux installation:

```
getfattr -d -m ".*" /etc/fstab
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/fstab
security.selinux="system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0"
```

which allows me to boot system again, but I'm still getting

```
inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)
```

failure from multiple commands, for example:

```
led 15 19:04:33 fedora kded5[1428]: inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)
```

**Questions:**

- what privilegeis needed to be able to inotify over this file? How to
  fix it(please be more verbose, I'm n00b)
- how can I find out from given error message, what permission is missing, so that I need not to ask beginner questions any more ;)

Answer (score 0):

The permission of /etc/fstab should be 644

```
root@VM:~# ls -l /etc/fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 695 Dec 22  2019 /etc/fstab
```

You will need to change the permission to 644 by doing a

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/fstab
```

If it's still not working can you execute the command`ls -l /etc/fstab` and put the output here

Comment: you are probably right. I was worried, that there is some other extended privilege. I still think I needed to add selinux role to be able to login again, but change from 600 to 644 seems to cured the ionotify report. Thanks